# JMeter Thread Group vs Concurrency Thread Group - very different results

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am trying to understand why I am seeing such different results when running the basic Thread Group vs Concurrency Thread group load test.
To narrow down the issue, I tried running Thread Group with just one thread/user for some time and got average, median, and p90 - all around **1,500 milliseconds**.

But when I run with the Concurrency Thread group, the aggregate report shows below **70ms** no matter if it's 1 or 300 RPS. Postman shows a response time of 1.3 seconds on average. So, I am thinking something is wrong with metrics captured by concurrency thread group.

My setup is very simple. Just one HTTP request that runs as a part of *Thread Group* in one case, and *Blazemeter's Concurrency Thread group* in 2nd case.

Thread Group report, with just 1 thread, and 1 RPS:
[image]

Concurrency Thread Group report, with 30 threads and 300 RPS:
[image]

Active threads for concurrent thread group:
[image]

Active threads for the basic thread group with 1 user:
[image]

Response time graph for concurrent group:
[image]

Sampler detailed view for basic thread group:[image]

Sampler detailed view for concurrent thread group:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) chart (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)) or equivalent from the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and you will find a lot of new information regarding your setup because the tests are not really the same

With regards to response time of 70 ms - I can think of 2 possible cases:

1. Establishing [TCP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-3-way-handshake-process/) and especially [SSL](https://www.ssl.com/article/ssl-tls-handshake-overview/) connection can take a lot of time for first iteration and subsequent iterations will be much faster. If you let "normal" Thread Group or Postman iterate more than once you will see similar results
2. It might be the case your server responds very fast with some form of an error message with HTTP Status Code 200 so it worth adding i.e. [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to check that the system under test returns expected response.

Comment: I do have a response assertion. The download part itself should take ~400 ms. At least that is what Postman steadily shows, in its breakdown. And yes, I do have active threads over time and a throughput shaping timer for the concurrent thread group. Added those charts to the question.